# Concatenate and count the number of elements in each row?

Tags: r

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), `ID without mask` = c(NA_character_, 
 NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), `Other Years` = c("2011", "2015", "2015", "2006, 2006, 2005, 2005, 2007", 
 "2014, 2011", "2007"), `Cut off Year` = c("2011", "2015", "2015", "2005", 
 "2011", "2007"), `2005` = c(NA, NA, NA, "30", "18", NA), `2006` = c(NA_character_, 
 NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
 ), `2007` = c("15", NA, "18", NA, "30, 18", NA), `2008` = c("16", 
 NA, NA, "30, 27", "18, 30", NA), `2009` = c("15", NA, NA, "20", 
 "30, 18", NA), `2010` = c(NA, NA, NA, "30, 20", NA, NA), `2011` = c(NA_character_, 
 NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
 ), `2012` = c(NA, NA, NA, "20, 30", NA, "26"), `2013` = c("15", 
 NA, "19", NA, NA, NA), `2014` = c(NA, NA, "18", NA, NA, NA), 
`2015` = c(NA, NA, "18", NA, "18", NA), `2016` = c(NA_character_, 
 NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
 NA_character_)), .Names = c("ID", "ID without mask", 
 "Other Years", "Cut off Year", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", 
 "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016"
 ), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Given the above data frame. I would like R to concatenate and count every element (for the years) in a row together and then output it in a new column.

Based on the "Cut off Year" column, I want R to concatenate the elements before the Cut off Year together in one column and the elements after the cut off year together in a second column (cut off year included).

So for the first row with a cut off year of 2011, the years 2007, 2008, and 2009 has 15, 16, 15 respectively, so that is 3 in total, so R should output the number 3 in the new column. After 2011, only 2013 has an element with a entry, hence the "after" column will only have the number 1.

Elements such as "30, 27" count as two, etc.

Here's the desired output:

```
structure(list(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), `ID without mask` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), `Other Years` = c("2011", "2015", "2015", "2006, 2006, 2005, 2005, 2007", 
"2014, 2011", "2007"), `Cut off Year` = c("2011", "2015", "2015", "2005", 
"2011", "2007"), `2005` = c(NA, NA, NA, "30", "18", NA), `2006` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), `2007` = c("15", NA, "18", NA, "30, 18", NA), `2008` = c("16", 
NA, NA, "30, 27", "18, 30", NA), `2009` = c("15", NA, NA, "20", 
"30, 18", NA), `2010` = c(NA, NA, NA, "30, 20", NA, NA), `2011` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), `2012` = c(NA, NA, NA, "20, 30", NA, "26"), `2013` = c("15", 
NA, "19", NA, NA, NA), `2014` = c(NA, NA, "18", NA, NA, NA), 
    `2015` = c(NA, NA, "18", NA, "18", NA), `2016` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), `Before cut` = c("3", "0", "3", "0", "7", "0"), `After cut` = c("1", "0", "1", "8", "1", "1")), .Names = c("ID", "Collab Years Patents", 
"Collab Years Publications", "Cut off Year", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", 
"2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "Before cut", "After cut"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "concatenation". The Before cut and After cut columns make sense, but all the other values are identical in your input and output.

Comment: @Gregor: If you're referring to the other columns before the cut off year column, then those are simply there to show the "dimensions" of my entire data frame. It's only the years column and the cut off column that are taken in to consideration. Maybe the word "concatenation" wasn't the right word to use here, but I basically meant to count the number of entries before and after separately like in the output data frame.

Comment: Okay, I would say that some of those entries have already been concatenated, perhaps, but no new concatenation is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert to a nice long format, count the values, and join back to the original:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

gather(df, key = "Year", value = "value", `2005`:`2016`) %>%
    mutate(val_count = str_count(value, pattern = ",") + 1) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarize(Before = sum(val_count * (Year < `Cut off Year`), na.rm = TRUE),
              After = sum(val_count * (Year >= `Cut off Year`), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    right_join(df) %>%
    select(1:3)
# Joining, by = "ID"
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     ID Before After
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1      3     1
2     2      0     0
3     3      3     1
4     4      0     8
5     5      7     1
6     6      0     1
```

I use `select(1:3)` to only show the relevant parts of the result - omit that line to get all the other columns too. To get the number of values, we add 1 to the number of commas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, when I try to run the `gather` function, I get the following error: `Error in UseMethod("gather_") : 
  no applicable method for 'gather_' applied to an object of class "function"`

Comment: You would get that error if you don't have a data frame named `df` in your workspace. Since you used the name `df` in your question, I used it in the answer. I normally use a name like `dd` which would produce a more informative error like "object 'dd' not found", but since `df()` is a built-in function (distribution function for the F distribution) you get the more confusing error instead.

Comment: You're right! Sorry, it's getting a bit late here. I'm getting an error when I execute the last code `Joining, by = "ID"`. It says: `Error: unexpected ',' in "Joining,"`. In my complete data frame, some of the IDs get skipped because I have previously removed some rows, so for instance it jumps from ID 285 to 287, etc. Could this be the cause of the error?

Comment: No, I just forgot a comment marker. "Joining by ID" is a message that prints when you run the previous line. It's not code you need to run. Edited the answer to fix it.